# Row Total In Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating A Report that has Row Total in Dynamic Pivot.
How to work with it?

Here's my code below:

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @whse VARCHAR(20)
Declare @dDate VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @itemcode VARCHAR(8000)
Declare @shift varchar(20)
Declare @DocEntry VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @isnullCol VARCHAR(8000)

Set @dDate =/* SELECT convert(varchar(15),Max(T0.DocDate),112) 
FROM OINM T0 WHERE T0.DocDate = */ convert(varchar(15),'20190602',112)

Set @whse = (Select max(a1.WhsCode) 
From OWHS a1 Where a1.WhsCode='A3 P-FG')

Set @shift = (select max(a2.u_shift)  
from OQUT a2 where a2.u_shift='2nd Shift')

SET @itemcode =  isnull( STUFF((Select DISTINCT ',  ''' + T1.ITEMCODE+'''' 
from OWTQ T0 
INNER JOIN WTQ1 t1 ON T0.DOCENTRY=T1.DOCENTRY
where t0.Docdate=@dDate AND T1.[FromWhsCod]=@whse 
and t0.u_Shift=@shift FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ,0)

SET @DocEntry =  isnull( STUFF((Select distinct  ',' +     convert(varchar(10),T0.DocEntry) 
from OWTQ T0 INNER JOIN WTQ1 t1 ON T0.DOCENTRY=T1.DOCENTRY
where t0.Docdate=@dDate AND T1.[FromWhsCod]=@whse 
and t0.u_Shift=@shift FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ,0)



SELECT  @Col = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + ltrim((t1.whscode)) 
from OWTQ T0  INNER JOIN WTQ1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
where T0.Docdate=@dDate and T1.[FromWhsCod]=@whse 
and t0.u_Shift like '%'+@shift+'%' 
ORDER BY '],[' + ltrim((t1.whscode)) 
FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SELECT @col += ',[RTotal]'
SELECT @isnullCol = 
SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+t1.whscode+'],0) AS ['+whscode+']' 
from OWTQ T0  INNER JOIN WTQ1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
where T0.Docdate=@dDate and T1.[FromWhsCod]=@whse 
and t0.u_Shift like '%'+@shift+'%' 
FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)

SELECT @isnullCol += ',ISNULL([RTotal],0) AS [Total]'



Set @Query = 
'Select  pvt.itemcode,'+@isnullCol+' from 
(Select ISNULL(CAST(Itemcode AS         
VARCHAR(50)),''RTotal'')Itemcode,t1.whscode,sum(t1.Quantity) as Total
FROM OWTQ T0 INNER JOIN WTQ1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
Where convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) = 
convert(varchar(15),'+@dDate+',112)  and t1.itemcode IN ('+ @itemcode +') 
and t0.DocEntry IN (' + @DocEntry + ')
group by t1.itemcode,t1.whscode )src
PIVOT (SUM(Total) For WhsCode IN ('+@Col+')) as pvt'

EXECUTE (@Query)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEtoC.png)

Comment: What error you are getting while executing the script?

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask how to get row total in dynamic pivot

Comment: Requirement not clear yet. You can add some sample data and your expected output with your question.

Comment: Hi sir. Sorry my 1st time to post here in stackoverflow. I've attached the picture.

Comment: You need (A19-O + A26-O A3 S-FG) in Another column?

Comment: Yes sir. how to do that if dynamic?
because that column will be change base on parameters.

Comment: Please check the answer added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Declare another variable as-
DECLARE @isnullCol_total VARCHAR(8000)

--Remove the following line from your script-
SELECT @isnullCol += ',ISNULL([RTotal],0) AS [Total]'

--Add this script to set value to newly declared variable
SET @isnullCol_total = REPLACE(@isnullCol,',','+')
SET @isnullCol_total = REPLACE(@isnullCol_total,'[','ISNULL([')+')'
SET @isnullCol_total = '('+REPLACE(@isnullCol_total,']','],0)')+' AS Total'

--You also have issue with ISNULL where you have some Sytax issue.
--The correct syntax should be as below-
ISNULL(CAST(Itemcode AS VARCHAR(50)),RTotal) Itemcode,

--Now write your dynamic SQL as below
Set @Query = 
'Select  pvt.itemcode,'+@isnullCol+' ,'+@isnullCol_total+' from 
(Select 
ISNULL(CAST(Itemcode AS VARCHAR(50)),RTotal) Itemcode,
t1.whscode,sum(t1.Quantity) as Total
FROM OWTQ T0 INNER JOIN WTQ1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
Where convert(varchar(15),T0.Docdate,112) = 
convert(varchar(15),'+@dDate+',112)  and t1.itemcode IN ('+ @itemcode +') 
and t0.DocEntry IN (' + @DocEntry + ')
group by t1.itemcode,t1.whscode )src
PIVOT (SUM(Total) For WhsCode IN ('+@Col+')) as pvt'

EXECUTE (@Query)
```

Comment: in this script, "Select  pvt.itemcode,'+@isnullCol+' ,'+@isnullCol+' ",
the return value were doubled.

and when i replace to "Select  pvt.itemcode,'+@isnullCol+' ,'@isnullCol_total' "

i got error  "Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'src'."

Comment: variable name was wrong. I have updated. if still issue exist, print the script rather than execution and check manually is there any more issue exist in the script or not.

Comment: got the error. I basically created the total form the column name you generated using stuff. but for total calculation, you need to add ISNULL checking for all column and replace by zero when null. can you try this yourself as I am out of home now. I can help you later. the idea is, new isnullcol_total shoud be something like- (isnull(col_1,0) + isnull(col_2,0)+......) total

Comment: Made some adjustment in populating variable @isnullCol_total. Can you please check now?

Comment: Also the ISNULL argument issue. You can check.

Comment: I change the script you've posted and i got the exact result
thanks for the support <3

SET @isnullCol_total ='('+Replace(+'isnull('+REPLACE(@col,',',',0)+isnull('),'[RTotal]','0,0)')+') AS Total'

Comment: @MhellLhemm Can you please give an up vote and accept the result if it really helped. That's the inspiration for me :)